# Firebase Test lab CI upload apks

Tags: android, firebase, service-accounts, google-cloud-sdk, firebase-test-lab

When setting up my buildserver to use Firebase Test Lab for espresso testing I keep running into the error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.test.android.run) Permission denied while fetching the default results bucket 
(Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud Tool Results API has not been used in project CLOUD_PROJECT_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/toolresults/overview?project=CLOUD_PROJECT_ID then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.).
Is billing enabled for project: [PROJECT_ID]?
```

When I try it on my own machine which is logged in via my own account, running the command below works correctly.

```
gcloud beta test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app-debug.apk \
  --test app-debug-androidTest.apk \
  --device-ids Nexus4,Nexus5 \
  --os-version-ids 18,21,25 \
  --locales en \
  --orientations portrait
```

On my build server I want to use a service-account but when I execute the command I get the error mentioned earlier. Does anyone know what the correct way is to set this up? Does the service-account need some special role beside `project editor`?

In the build script I execute the commands below to authenticate and set the project before uploading the APK's

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
gcloud auth activate-service-account service-account@email.address --key-file ~/gcloud-service-key.json
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured it out. If you want to use service accounts for Firebase Test Lab you have to enable `Cloud Tool Results API` which can only be enabled through [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) and not the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you're probably using it from a CI/CD server and using Service Accounts for authentication... Don't do as I did, don't use a google cloud platform service account. Instead, **use a Firebase Service Accounts** json key from here

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/settings/serviceaccounts/